# Getting the sum of all values in a nested list dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Banking_Deposits = {'January':[15000,9800,10100],  'Feburary':[2500,1400,14100], 'March': [20000,78366]}

total_dep = sum(Banking_Deposits.values())
```

I would like to get the value sum of the total deposit made in all the 3 months. However I was returned with this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The more intuitive way would be to do a nested sum:

```
sum(sum(x) for x in Banking_Deposits.values())
```

You can also use [`sum`'s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) `start` parameter to join the lists first:

```
sum(sum(Banking_Deposits.values(), []))
```

The default value for `start` is 0, which is why you get the error: `0 + [...]` does not compute. Not to mention that your original sum would yield a very long list instead of a number, since that's what you get from adding lists together.

A better way to chain the lists would be using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable), which wouldn't allocate multiple lists as byproducts:

```
sum(chain.from_iterable(Banking_Deposits.values()))
```

[@Primusa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51345317/2988730) suggests an equivalent and more intuitive method for flattening the values that I highly recommend.

Answer (score 3):

At the moment `sum()` isn't looping through each deposit in the dictionary, it's looping through each list inside of `Banking_Deposits.values()`. Since the initializer for sum is 0, which is an int, you're getting the error when sum tries to add each list to 0. A solution would be to flatten the lists first before taking the sum:

`sum(val for value in Banking_Deposits.values() for val in value)`

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate through the dictionary, get their values by assigning the key, and sum it. Like this:

```
Banking_Deposits = {'January':[15000,9800,10100],  'Feburary':[2500,1400,14100], 'March': [20000,78366]}
store_1 = []
for x in Banking_Deposits:
    store_1.append(sum(Banking_Deposits[x]))
print(sum(store_1))
```

Comment: You aren't summing the total and your loop does an unnecessary lookup since you can iterate over the values instead of the keys.